# SendAsync in Web API Return null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to return an appropriate error message when a user tries to call the service when their authorization token has expired or if they have an invalid token.

The problem I'm having is the first time it is called, the message is sent properly, but after the first time the SendAsync method is called 4 times and the message data returns null.

I'm confused as to why it loops 4 times, and I tried stepping through it, but I can't get any further in the code.

Here is the code:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
                                                           CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Headers != null)
        {

             // ....

             if (request.Headers.GetValues(CustomTokenHeader).FirstOrDefault() == null)
             {
                  //unauthorized response(401)
                  return FromResult(_unauthorizedResponse);
             }
             var authHeader = request.Headers.GetValues(CustomTokenHeader).FirstOrDefault();
             if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authHeader))
             {
                 //unauthorized response(401)
                 return FromResult(_unauthorizedResponse);
             }

             //authenticate token
             return HandleTokenAuthentication(request, cancellationToken, authHeader);
        }
    }

    static Task<T> FromResult<T>(T t)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        tcs.SetResult(t);
        return tcs.Task;
    }


    private Task<HttpResponseMessage> HandleTokenAuthentication(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, string authHeader)
    {
        //parse token
        var token = ParseToken(authHeader);
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            //unauthorized response(401)
            return FromResult(_unauthorizedResponse);
        }

        //decrypt token
        var tokenInfo = DecryptToken(token);
        if (tokenInfo == null)
        {
            //unauthorized response(401)
            return FromResult(_unauthorizedResponse);
        }

        //validate token
        var claims = ValidateToken(tokenInfo, token);
        if (claims == null)
        {
            //unauthorized response(401)
            return FromResult(_unauthorizedTokenExpired);
        }
        var principal = CheckCustomAuthorization(claims);
         if (principal == null)
        {
            //unauthorized response(401)
            return FromResult(_unauthorizedResponse);
        }
        if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            var loginFailureMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(((AgencyClaims)principal.Identity).LoginFailureReason)
            };

            return FromResult(loginFailureMessage);
        }
        //assign principal
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                               .ContinueWith(task => AuthorizedResponse(request, task.Result));
    }

    static HttpResponseMessage AuthorizedResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if ((request.Method == HttpMethod.Get && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK
            && !response.Headers.Contains(CustomTokenHeader))
            || (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created
            && !response.Headers.Contains(CustomTokenHeader)))
        {
            var token = ((AgencyClaims) Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).Token;
            response.Headers.Add(CustomTokenHeader, Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(token)));
        }
        return response;
    }

readonly HttpResponseMessage _unauthorizedResponse =
        new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { Content = new StringContent("PROPER ERROR MESSAGE")};
```

Successful response:

```
 <data contentType="text/plain; charset=utf-8" contentLength="21"><![CDATA[Authentication failed]]></data>
```

Here is the response after the first successful response:

```
<data contentType="null" contentLength="0"><![CDATA[]]></data>
```

Here is part of the request:

```
GET http://localhost:20559/api/Service?Name=Jack HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Show us the code for `HandleTokenAuthentication`

Comment: Sure. Just updated the code. I also added the `AuthorizedResponse` method.

Comment: I'm not sure that that would be the problem though, since the message is returned before the `HandleTokenAuthentication` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to resolve the issue. The `_unauthorizedResponse` class variable is somehow allowing the code to run once through successfully, but not a second time. This issue is not related to the readonly modifier, since it still doesn't work without it. I'm not sure how this works (and maybe someone on here can explain), but by moving them into the local scope within the method it is able to run correctly each time.